# Why is the foliage turning yellow on this climbing indoor vine?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, plant-health, leaves, plant-care

I've had this plant in water until it grew enough roots and a few more leaves. I'm not sure what kind of plant this is, but its starting to grow longer; when it was only one little leaf when I rescued it.

I've noticed a couple of **yellow** streaks a few weeks ago. But now there's more and the yellow spots are getting wider. I water once a week. I've only fertilized once with Miracle-Gro Fertilizer. I give it morning sun until the sun goes down.

I thought I was taking good care of this plant, what am I doing wrong? 
[image: Yellowing][image: Full plant]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like natural variegation to me...looks like a typical golden pothos ([*Epipremnum aureum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epipremnum_aureum)). It's supposed to have these marks. They show up and contrast best with good lighting.

Don't worry about this - it's natural, and healthy.

Comment: See http://gardening.stackexchange.com/search?q=pothos for info on how to grow these.

Comment: Also called philodendron

Comment: @Escoce you may be thinking of variegated heartleaf Philodendron ([*Philodendron hederaceum* "Variegata"](http://www.onlineplantguide.com/Plant-Details/3206/), syn. *P. scandens* "Variegata"), a very similar plant. Or you may have heard people erroneously call a golden pothos a philodendron. Either way, what the OP has is the pothos.